# Possibility of ants not being able to cross a grid shaped bridge

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

The problem is really simple, but I have absolutely no idea on how to solve it.

So there is an ant who really wants to get to the other side of a grid shaped bridge. However, a person decides to stop the ant from crossing over, so he gets a coin and starts throwing it for each of the 28 black line segments.

If the coin that he threw is a tail, he cuts out that line segment, and if the coin that he threw is a head, he leaves the line segment alone.

After he does this for every 28 black line segment, what is the possibility that the ant still can cross the bridge?

[image: Ants can move only on the lines]

Comment: Seems tricky.  Where did this come from?

Comment: One of my professors decided to give the students a problem to think about just for fun and he didin't even tell us the solution (probably completely forgot about the fact that he ever gave the problem to the students), but I really want to know how this can be solved

Comment: Doing some googling, I found [this](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~zhangw/files/DASFAA2011_probabilisticreachability.pdf) paper which is relevant. It appears this problem is NP-hard for general graphs.  So an answer would probably be either a brute-force count or exploit some special structure of this grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the dual ant that tries to get from one green line to the other across the gray bridge:

[image: dual problem]

Exactly one of the ants can cross. By symmetry, the probability for either to be able to cross is $\frac12$.

Comment: So they are playing Hex. Brilliant!

Comment: Wow that is simply brilliant.  WOW

Comment: @joriki Can you prove how exactly one of the ants can cross ?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan: Each dual gray link remains if the corresponding black link is removed. It can't be that both ants can cross, since their paths would have to cross and the crossing point would have to have both a gray and a black link. Slightly less obviously, it also can't be that neither ant can cross. Think of it as a maze: Put your hand to the wall to the right of the entrance and follow it. Since the process is finite, the wall either leads you to the exit or to the wall to the left of the entrance, and in the latter case there's a contiguous wall from the right to the left.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan: If you want to read more about this sort of duality argument, take a look at [percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory) and [percolation thresholds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold).