# Bond percolation crossing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-graphs

I know nothing about percolation theory. But I would like to learn how one solves the following basic problem.

Consider a grid of size $(n+1)\times n$. Each edge is assigned 0 or 1 with equal probability, independently. A crossing is a path that joins the left and right sides of the rectangle, and consists entirely of edges valued 1. Show that such grid has crossing with probability 1/2.

I feel that we need to use symmetry of this problem in some way but not sure how.

Comment: You need to look at the dual grid (connect two faces if there is no edge separating them), and note that an up-down crossing in the dual implies no left-right crossing in the regular, and they partition the space, and then invoke symmetry. I right now don't have time to type it up as an answer but I am leaving it as a hint. Will get back to it later assuming noone has written an answer.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but if there's an up-down crossing in the dual, couldn't there still be a left-right crossing in the regular if the path crosses the up-down crossing along the top or bottom of the grid?

Comment: @E-A I would appreciate if you do find time to type it. Otherwise, is there a reference?

Comment: @forgottenarrow It's the canonical solution. Try to draw the dual crossing from top to bottom in red and note that it separates the box into two connected components. Hence, there can not be a left-right crossing at the same time.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Sorry, there's something I'm still not understanding here. The dual crossing partitions the dual grid. But suppose the up-down crossing is composed of the 2nd column of boxes. In the regular grid, this implies that all edges between the 2nd and 3rd column are missing _except_ the edges on the top and bottom rows. These edges border only a single face and so they do not represent edges (or non-edges) in the dual grid. As a result, even when the dual grid has an up-down crossing, these edges may still remain in the regular grid, so there could still be a left-right crossing.

Comment: @forgottenarrow Sure, you should not look at the dual grid strictly inside your rectangle. You should look at the dual domain which will contain faces that are not strictly contained in your first rectangle. The important part is that every edge of your domain should correspond to exactly one edge in your dual domain just like it is when you define the dual lattice.

Comment: @DanielLi your question has apparently been already asked in SE though. under a subtle disguise https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641112/possibility-of-ants-not-being-able-to-cross-a-grid-shaped-bridge/3641146#3641146

Comment: @DanielLi (and I guess @forgottenarrow) if that link is not clear, post a comment and I can expand.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou@DanielLi Ah, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possibility of ants not being able to cross a grid shaped bridge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641112/possibility-of-ants-not-being-able-to-cross-a-grid-shaped-bridge)